# How to localize beamer's mathematical blocks to Hebrew?

Tags: beamer, babel, hebrew, block, right-to-left

The following LaTeX code was saved in `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer-rl}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[main, import]{hebrew}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelfont{sf}{FreeSans}
\babelfont{tt}{FreeMono}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}
D
\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}
T
\end{theorem}
\begin{corollary}
C
\end{corollary}
\begin{proof}
P
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The code creates a Hebrew presentation with a single slide containing four mathematical blocks.

Then the following commands were executed in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
```

Consequently, the file `~/Test.pdf` was generated. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed as follows.

[image: A Hebrew presentation with math blocks]

Bear in mind that Hebrew is a right-to-left language, and so the text's right-justification is expected and correct, and does not constitute a problem.

Note that in three of the mathematical blocks: `definition`, `theorem`, and `corollary`, the block's title is written in English, whereas in the fourth block, `proof`, the title was automatically generated in Hebrew.

I'd like all the mathematical blocks to behave like the `proof` block in having automatically generated Hebrew titles. How can these environments be localized to Hebrew, when the presentation's language is Hebrew? Where do these environments get their titles from?

Comment: Please include the translations for definition, theorem and corollary in your question

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz What does it matter? You can use DEFINITION, THEOREM, COROLLARY, in capital English letters.

Comment: beamer uses in most places (proof is an exception of the rule) the translator package to translate strings. You can add a translation eg. with `\deftranslation[to=hebrew]{Theorem}{xxxxx}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. Where can I see an example of a complete localization for beamer? Are there files, similar to `.lbx` for `biblatex`, where all the localization strings for a given language are concentrated?

Comment: Well if you do what @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz asked you she can probably provide something.  She maintains beamer.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I would translate *definition* as הגדרה, *theorem* as משפט, and *corollary* as מסקנה. Are there other math environments built into `beamer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beamer uses the `translator` package to get translation for these strings. For most commonly used languages it comes with `.dict` files which already have all the translations, but for hebrew they don't yet exist.

You can create a new `.dict` file for hebrew like this:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer-rl}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[main, import]{hebrew}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelfont{sf}{FreeSans}
\babelfont{tt}{FreeMono}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{translator-theorem-dictionary-Hebrew.dict}
\providetranslation{Definition}{הגדרה}
\providetranslation{Theorem}{משפט}
\providetranslation{Corollary}{מסקנה}
\end{filecontents*}

\uselanguage{hebrew}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}
D
\end{definition}
\begin{theorem}
T
\end{theorem}
\begin{corollary}
C
\end{corollary}
\begin{proof}
P
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(please consider opening a PR at https://github.com/josephwright/translator/ to add hebrew dict files so other users can use them, too!)

Comment: Why is the command `\uselanguage{hebrew}` required? Shouldn't the Hebrew strings be retrieved automatically from the dictionary file when the document's main language is Hebrew, as set by `babel`?

Comment: Also: why is it `\uselanguage{hebrew}` with a lowercase `h` rather than `Hebrew` with a capital `H`? According to the `translator` manual "The names used by the translator package are the English names commonly used for these languages. Thus, the name for the English language is English, the name for German is German." (Section 1.2.2 *Language Names*, on p. 3 of the current version, 2021-05-31)

Comment: @EvanAad If the language is set on the document level and not only for the babel package, you don't need to manually set `\uselanguage`, see e.g. https://pastebin.com/u8Qw2jEe (no idea how one would do this with hebrew, bidi freaks out when I tried this...)

Comment: I see. Thanks. What about my other question, about the capitalization of the language's name?

Comment: @EvanAad No idea about the capitalisation.

Comment: I now understand the capitalization issue, and would like to explain.

Comment: Despite the quote from the manual, [given above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667704/how-to-localize-beamers-mathematical-blocks-to-hebrew#comment1660366_667714), the `translator` package does not use the common English language names automatically unless this has been prearranged in one of two ways:

Comment: 1. The language name, in its `babel` form, was passed to the `translator` package as an option, either directly, or indirectly by passing it as a class option, which then percolates down as an option to all the loaded packages, including the `translator` package.

Comment: 2. The `translator` command `\languagealias` was called. (In fact, when the language is passed as a package option, `\languagealias` is called automatically behind the scenes.)

Comment: This is true of all languages known to the `translator` package (which Hebrew is one of), not just Hebrew; German too, as well as French, etc. The only language that gets preferential treatment by the `translator` package is English, which is treated as a default language.

Comment: However, unlike German, French, etc. Hebrew can't be passed as a class option, since then it will percolate as an option to the `babel` package, and, for some reason unknown to me, the `beamer` document class (but not the `article` document class) is incompatible with the `babel` method of including Hebrew as a package option; rather, Hebrew needs to be imported with the `\babelprovide` command. (Again, this only affects `beamer`, not `article`. With `article` it is possible to specify Hebrew as a package option thus: `\usepackage[bidi=basic,hebrew,provide=*]{babel}`.)

Comment: @EvanAad Hebrew can be passed as a class option, just not with babel. I was chatting with a hebrew polyglossia user last night and the class option worked just fine.

Comment: I have submitted Hebrew translations for all the standard dictionaries that are part of the `translator` package. [Here's the GitHub ticket.](https://github.com/josephwright/translator/issues/25)

Comment: @EvanAad Great! Thanks!